# Can Continuous Looping Cause Thread Problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an app that runs a lot of threads. It was my first attempt at a multi-threaded app and it does not use a thread pool, I simply spawn my own threads. The methods they run just loop indefinitely. Can this cause problems? The reason I ask is that my app seems to run fine for about 10 minutes and then almost comes to a complete halt. Any tips appreciated. Cheers.

EDIT: I'll just add a little info. The app is an account creator. I would like it to be able to run 100+ threads at all times. The threads run non stop and are NOT constantly being created, they are only created once and then they should make accounts until I close the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) very carefully, it is what I believe one of the best threading resources available. Spinning the processor is not recommended since it wastes CPU resources. It is better to block a thread when it is not required to do any work, and awake once it is required to act upon signals.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .net 4.0 you should look at using the Task Parallel Library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

MS have done a lot of the hard work here (thread pooling etc.), which should help you to avoid some of the common threading problems.

For your own issue, are you sure you're not locking something and then not always removing the lock in your loop somewhere?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of my locks are fine. On the last test, my app ran through the method a good 7000 times with 20 threads running before it bogged down. I'll have a look at that link though.

Answer (score 0):

technically looping indefinitely won't cause issues, it isn't best design practice in most cases. With your approach you need to ensure no memory leaks are occuring and objects are correctly disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can cause many problems if you create threads without bound.

1. There is a limit to how many threads that can be efficiently scheduled by the OS and executed by the CPU.  For CPU-bound operations, a good rule of thumb is to keep the thread count close to the number of CPU cores.
2. Continuously creating and destroying threads causes a lot of unnecessary overhead, especially for short-lived operations.  Thread pools are the best approach to reduce these costs.
3. If you create too many threads, you will eventually run out of stack space and your program will simply crash.  Even before that point, you will probably end up using too many system resources and slow down other tasks on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

There's looping and looping..  Many threads are designed to loop indefinitely for the life of an application.  As explained by the other posters, CPU-loops that do nothing but spin-wait are unnecessary and wasteful. Loops doing useful work and loops containing blocking calls, eg. on I/O or producer-consumer queues, are just fine - leave them to do their job for the whole app run.

Again with the other posters, look at pools etc.  Continual create/terminate/destroy threads is expensive and error-prone.

Comment: I have updated my question with more info on my app. I am not continually creating threads and destroying them. I am only creating them and then letting them run until I close the app.